# Mysql query on summing quantites

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT a. id,
       a.kataloski_broj, 
       SUM(a.quantity) AS zbroj, 
       entry_type_desc, 
       posting_date, 
       item_category, 
       product_group,
       b.nabavna_cijena as neto_nabavna,
       b.neto_VPC,
       b.preporucena_VPC,
       c.nabavna_cijena as rabat_nabavna,
       c.VPC,
       d.VPC as NAV_VPC,
       d.PVPC as NAV_PVPC
    FROM prodaja_zaliha a
  LEFT JOIN kalkulacija_stavke b ON a.kataloski_broj = b.kataloski_broj
  LEFT JOIN kalkulacija_stavke_rabat c ON a.kataloski_broj = c.kataloski_broj
  LEFT JOIN katalog_pribora_item d ON a.kataloski_broj = d.kataloski_broj_NAV
    WHERE a.entry_type_desc = 'Prodaja' 
    AND YEAR(a.posting_date) = '2015' 
    AND a.kataloski_broj = 'M1200'
  GROUP BY a.id ASC
```

Why this query is not returning correct value? SUM(a.quantity) AS zbroj is returning 1432 instead of 182 rows. What is wrong here?

Comment: Because your join is multiplying the number of rows.  You would need to aggregate the data before doing the join to get the right answer.

Comment: How should I do that?

Comment: Why do you expect 182 rows? What do you get when select count(distinct id) from prodaja_zaliha where entry_type_desc = 'Prodaja' and YEAR(posting_date) = '2015' and kataloski_broj = 'M1200'

Comment: I have counted rows without joins and is giving 182. I have reworked my query and now is working. I will post it below, so maybe it can help someone. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ABS(SUM(quantity)) as zbroj, a.kataloski_broj, a.id, a.entry_type_desc, a.posting_date, a.item_category, a.product_group
  FROM prodaja_zaliha a
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT kataloski_broj, nabavna_cijena, neto_VPC, preporucena_VPC
  FROM kalkulacija_stavke
  GROUP BY kataloski_broj) AS b
  ON a.kataloski_broj = b.kataloski_broj
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT kataloski_broj, nabavna_cijena, VPC
    FROM kalkulacija_stavke_rabat
    GROUP BY kataloski_broj) AS c
  ON a.kataloski_broj = c.kataloski_broj
  LEFT JOIN(SELECT kataloski_broj_NAV, VPC, PVPC
    FROM katalog_pribora_item
    GROUP BY kataloski_broj_NAV) AS d
  ON a.kataloski_broj = d.kataloski_broj_NAV
WHERE a.kataloski_broj = 'M1200' AND
  a.entry_type_desc = 'Prodaja' AND
YEAR(a.posting_date) = '2015'
```

This is query which is returning correct result!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help

```
SELECT a. id,
           a.kataloski_broj, 
        e.zbroj  as zbroj, 
           entry_type_desc, 
           posting_date, 
           item_category, 
           product_group,
           b.nabavna_cijena as neto_nabavna,
           b.neto_VPC,
           b.preporucena_VPC,
           c.nabavna_cijena as rabat_nabavna,
           c.VPC,
           d.VPC as NAV_VPC,
           d.PVPC as NAV_PVPC
        FROM prodaja_zaliha a
    inner JOIN (select id, SUM(quantity) AS zbroj  FROM prodaja_zaliha  WHERE entry_type_desc = 'Prodaja' 
        AND YEAR(posting_date) = '2015' 
        AND kataloski_broj = 'M1200') as e on e.id=a.id
      LEFT JOIN kalkulacija_stavke b ON a.kataloski_broj = b.kataloski_broj
      LEFT JOIN kalkulacija_stavke_rabat c ON a.kataloski_broj = c.kataloski_broj
      LEFT JOIN katalog_pribora_item d ON a.kataloski_broj = d.kataloski_broj_NAV
        WHERE a.entry_type_desc = 'Prodaja' 
        AND YEAR(a.posting_date) = '2015' 
        AND a.kataloski_broj = 'M1200'
        GROUP BY a.id
        ORDER BY a.id DESC
```